# How do I assign indices to my Jekyll blog posts?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I would like to add index as a variable to my Jekyll blog posts so my post URLs have numbers instead of titles.
Example of what I had in mind:

```
---
index: 0
layout: post
title:  "Hello World"
date:   2021-03-04 15:22:22 +0100
categories: intro, AI, cryptocurrency, quantum computing, web development
permalink: /:title
---
```

and the desired link:

```
https://dorijan-cirkveni.github.io/0
```

Answer (score 0):

Each post has to be in a file named `YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP`. The title in the file name is different from the title in the post.

By replacing the title in the file name with an index, I was able to accomplish my desired result.